# Does spring-session support saving the session when "setAttribute" is called on the session?

Tags: spring-session

It appears the primary behavior of Spring session is to save the session when the HttpResponse is committed.

Does spring-session also support saving the session when "setAttribute" is called on the session ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Spring Session with either Redis or Hazelcast session stores, you can set the flush mode to `IMMEDIATE` (`ON_SAVE` is the default). This will result in changes to session being persistent to underlying store immediately as they are made.

Take a look at [`@EnableRedisHttpSession`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/master/spring-session-data-redis/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/annotation/web/http/EnableRedisHttpSession.java) or [`@EnableHazelcastHttpSession`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/master/spring-session-hazelcast/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/hazelcast/config/annotation/web/http/EnableHazelcastHttpSession.java) annotations.